# How should I normalize this database design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm trying to design a database. I've got a design that seems to me to be normalized to [Fourth Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) - but still I think is broken, and I can't for the life of me work out how to fix it.

Background: we have four types of tests, and a couple dozen tests of each type. We run the tests in batches, where each batch contains tests of only one type. So a test result belongs to a batch, and also belongs to a test. Which gives a database plan something like this:

[image: Diagram with Result going Many-to-One to Test and Result also going Many-to-One to Batch, and both Batch and Test going Many-to-One to TypeOfTest]

The problem is that this design allows for a Result that is for a Test of Type A, but that Result is in a Batch for Type B.

One thing I cannot do is combine the Test and Batch tables in to one table. There is a new Batch each week, while a Test lasts for months or years. And a Batch can contain many Tests (though always of the same Type), and a Test is usually done many times in many Batches.

I could insert a many-to-many join between Test and Batch, but I can't immediately see how that would help anything.

Is there a clean way to re-organise this so that we don't have the circular join path? Is this necessary? Or desirable?

Or should I just go with what I've got, and stop worrying about it?  :-)

[Edit 1] Note that the Test has details on how it runs, who fixes problems found, etc which remain constant over multiple Batches, so the Test must exist independantly of any Batches that it may (or may not) run in.

[Edit 2] It has been pointed out that it would be better to have a TestBatch table, which gives us this structure:

[image: Now with TestBatch in the place where Result used to be, and Result going Many-to-One to TestBatch]

I agree this is a good idea, but that doesn't actually fix the problem. It just moves the problem from Result to TestBatch. We can now have a TestBatch that is for a Test of Type A, but that TestBatch has in a Batch for Type B.

[Edit 3] Thanks to @philip-kelley 's excellent suggestion, I believe we have an answer. First, we link TestBatch directly back to Type, thus:

[image]

This doesn't immediately fix the problem. In fact it makes it worse - there could now be one Type for the Test, a different Type for the Batch, and a third Type joined directly from the TestBatch.

But the second step is to change the foreign key from TestBatch to Test, so that it includes the Type as well as the TestID. And to change the foreign key to Batch to include the Type as well as the BatchID.

That way, we can be certain that the TestBatch has the same Type as the Test, and the Batch.

Comment: Wait, I’m missing something. If `each batch contains tests of only one type`, and `a test result belongs to a batch`, then how can a `Result that is for a Test of Type A` be `in a Batch for Type B`?

Comment: In the real world - it can't. Each result is for a particular test, and a particular batch, and that test and that batch *must* be of the same type.

In my database design - it's easy to have a Result for a Test of Type A, but the Result is in a Batch of Type B. And that's why I think my design is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@HLGEM’s answer describes the logical model, with some physical model details. A physical implementation that supports *and enforces* your business rules would look something like this. (This is psuedo-code, showing only the key columns--you'd want to add columns for attributes like Name, Score, etc. Actual implementation details are system-dependent and can get a bit tricky, but any RDBMS should be able to support this. Note that all columns listed are NOT NULLable.)

```
CREATE TABLE TestType
  TestType    int
  <primary key on TestType>


CREATE TABLE Test
  TestId       int
  TestType     int
  <primary key on TestId>
  <foreign key into TestType on column TestType>


CREATE TABLE Batch
  BatchId      int
  TestType     int
  <primary key on BatchId>
  <foreign key into TestType on column TestType>


CREATE TABLE TestInBatch
  TestInBatchId  int
  TestId         int
  BatchId        int
  TestType       int
  <primary key on TestInBatchId>
  <unique constraint on TestId, BatchId>
  <foreign key on (TestId, TestType) into Test, columns (TestId, TestType)>
  <foreign key on (BatchId, TestType) into Batch, columns (BatchId, TestType)>


CREATE TABLE Result
  ResultId       int
  TestInBatchId  int
  <primary key on ResultId>
  <foreign key into TestInBatch on column TestInBatchId>
```

Comment: Of course! You've added a TestType field in TestInBatch, and used it as a second field in the foreign keys for Test and Batch. Which means the TestType is always fixed for a given TestInBatch, and it always matches both the Test and the Batch. Perfect!  :-)

Comment: If we're going to have a TestType field in the TestInBatch table, to use in the foreign keys for Test and Batch, then I'll probably use that field as a direct foreign key link back to the TestType table as well. I'm using Laravel, so being able to link directly will be convenient.

Comment: With the foreign key between TestType and both Test and Batch, and the foreign keys from them to TestInBatch, a foreign key between TestInBatch and TestType is not strictly necessary... but when it helps with implementation or performance, go ahead.

Comment: @BrendanWhite The general topic is"subtyping" under  database/sql and a TestType value is a type "tag" or "discriminator".

Answer (score 1):

Create a TestBatch table that contains the tests associated with a particular batch. Use the PK of that table as the FK in the results table.

You need TestBatch in any event because the tests associated with a particular batch are a historical moment in time that you need to capture.  Each time you build a new batch, there may be new tests added but you don't want them associated with earlier, completed batches.

TestBatch joins to both test and batch and contains BatchID, TestID and  an ID of its own.  Then the Results table contains the ID from TestBatch as its foreign key.

So to see the results against this, you would join results to TestBatch and then grab descriptive details from both the Test and the Batch tables like so:

```
Select r.ResultId, R.Col1, r.col2, b.BatchId, b.batchdate, t.testId, t.Test_description
From Results r
join TestBatch tb on r.TestBatchid = tb.TestBatchid
join Batch b on tb.batchid = b.batchid
join Test t on tb.testid = t.testid
```

Type would likely be used mostly to create the record for TestBatch at the time the batch was created. 
And to join to the above to filter by type  In this case you generally only want to join to Type to Batch or Test but not both at the same time.

To show you a little of how this works with data (Forget the results table for now and the official FKs and PKs which you can see in @PhillipKelleys excellent answer) Code is written for SQL server, I used temp tables so you could play around a bit before committing to a structure, but remove the # signs if you want to create real tables. Identity is what SQl server uses to create auto generated fields substitute with the code for your database backend to do something similar.:

```
Create table #type (Typeid int identity, TypeDescription varchar(100))

Insert into #type (TypeDescription)
values ('Geography'),  ('History'),  ('Biology'),  ('Math')

Create table #Batch (BatchID int identity, TypeID int, BatchDate datetime)

insert into #Batch (TypeID, BatchDate)
values (1, getdate()-1), (1, getdate() +2) , (4, getdate())

Create table  #Test (testId int identity, TestDescription varchar(50), TypeId int)
Insert into #Test (TestDescription, TypeId )
values ('fall midterm', 1), ('fall final', 1),  ('fall midterm', 3), ('fall final', 3), ('fall final', 2), ('fall midterm', 4), ('fall final', 4)

Create  table #TESTBATCH (TestBatchID int identity, TestID int, BATCHID int )

Insert into #testBatch ( BATCHID, TestID)
values(1, 1), (1, 2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,6), (3, 7)

select * from #type
select * from #Batch
select * from #test
select * from #testBatch
```

This would show the details of all the current batches

```
select B.batchdate, t.TypeDescription, te.TestDescription, t2.TypeDescription
from #testBatch tb
join #batch b on b.batchid = tb.batchid
join #type t on t.typeid = b.typeid
join #test te on te.testid = tb.testid
join #type t2 on t2.typeid = te.typeid
```

This would show all the current tests even the ones with no current batch

```
select  te.TestDescription, t2.TypeDescription, B.batchdate, t.TypeDescription
from #test te 
join #type t2 on t2.typeid = te.typeid
left join #testBAtch tb on te.testID = tb.testId
left join #batch b on b.batchid = tb.batchid
left join #type t on t.typeid = b.typeid
```

Comment: Good point - I can see how a TestBatch table would be worth having. 

However it wouldn't fix the original problem. It would just mean that I'd have the problem on TestBatch instead of Result.

For example - you suggest that I generally only want to join to Type to Batch or Test but not both at the same time. My question is - what if I join from TestBatch to Batch to Type in one function, but I join from TestBatch to Test to Type in another? And what if the Batch has a different Type to the Test? 

I'd have two different Types for the same TestBatch, depending on which function I'm in.

Comment: Type is a lookup table. You woudl only want to use it in a join when you want to lookup the text value of a specified type. If you need that for both test and Batch in the same query, you join to it twice but maintain the real relationship through test batch. In general since you say a batch is only going to be for one type at a time, you would want to join to Type only through batch unless batch is not part of the query at all.